# The number of ways to pile n white circles, when in the bottom row there are n white circles?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, combinations, recursion, multisets

I am struggling with this Question:
What are the number of ways to pile circles (as long as they don't fall from the sides) when in the bottom row there are $n$ white circles. each row can hold maximum a number of one less circles than the row underneath. for example for $n=3$ the answer is 5.  [image]

i think it might be recurrence that we have $a_1=1$ and $a_2=2$ but i don't know what the formula can be.

Comment: Counting by hand, I get $1,2,5,13,41,129$, which isn't in OEIS, but I may well have made a mistake.

Comment: I think u have a mistake and its $1,2,5,14...$ it might has to do with Catalan numbers?

Comment: I did make a mistake; I coded it up now, and the numbers coincide with the Catalan numbers up to $a_7=429$.

Comment: but do u have a combinatoric way to prove why its Catalan numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put one more row with $n+1$ balls underneath the arrangement. Start at the leftmost of these balls, and in each step, go right by half a ball width, staying on existing balls, moving up if there's a ball there and down if not. The resulting paths are precisely the Dyck paths of length $2n$, which are counted by the Catalan numbers.

Comment: I am still having trouble to compare this problem to Dyck's paths. for example what is the path for the middle balls pics above?

Comment: @TomerLevy: Up, down [since there's no ball if you go up], up, up [since now there's a ball], down, down.